# Read a file line by line for every observation in a dataset

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a program that takes a text file, replaces any macro references within it, and appends it to a single output file.  The macro references are generated as I iterate over the observations in a dataset.

I'm having trouble trying to get it to read the entire text file for each observation in my source table.  I think there's an implicit `stop` instruction related to my use of the `end=` option on the `infile` statement that is preventing my set statement from iterating over each record.

I've simplified the template and code, examples below:

Here is the template that I'm trying to populate:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (name,age)      
VALUES (&name,&age);
```

Here is the SAS code:

```
filename dest "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\backfill.sql";

data _null_;
  attrib line length=$1000;

  set sashelp.class;

  file dest;
  infile "sql_template.sas" end=template_eof;

  call symput('name', quote(cats(name)));
  call symput('age' , cats(age));

  do while (not template_eof);
    input;
    line = resolve(_infile_);
    put line;
  end;
run;
```

Running the above code produces the desired output file but only for the first observation in the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it that way since after the first observation you are already at the end of the input text file. So your `DO WHILE` loop only runs for the first observation.

Here is a trick that I learned a long time ago on SAS-L. Toggle between two input files so that you can start at the top of the input file again.

First let's create your example template program and an empty dummy file.

```
filename template temp;
filename dummy temp;

data _null_;
  file template;
  put 'INSERT INTO some_table (name,age)'
    / '  VALUES (&name,&age)'
    / ';'
  ;
  file dummy ;
run;
```

Now let's write a data step to read the input data and use `RESOLVE()` function to convert the text.

```
filename result temp;

data _null_;
  length filename $256 ;
  file result ;
  set sashelp.class;
  call symputx('name', catq('1at',name));
  call symputx('age' , age);

  do filename=pathname('template'),pathname('dummy');
    infile in filevar=filename end=eof ;
    do while (not eof);
      input;
      _infile_ = resolve(_infile_);
      put _infile_;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

The resulting file will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (name,age)
  VALUES ('Alfred',14)
;
INSERT INTO some_table (name,age)
  VALUES ('Alice',13)
;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this I was able to get it working.  Are you able to explain why my original attempt does not work?  I'd like to improve my understanding...

Comment: You read the full input text file on the first iteration of the data step. Then there was no way to tell SAS to start reading the text file from the beginning when you got to the next observation of the data step.  By having it use the FILEVAR option it will close and reopen the input text file when the value of the filename changes.

Comment: Ah, sorry I needed to be more clear in my prior comment.  The thing that confused me was that my code actually stops processing my dataset after observation 1!  If I change my `data _null_` statement to `data tmp` then you will see in the notes it only reads a single observation. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: I don't think it stops, at least it doesn't when I try it. But it never enters to the `DO WHILE` loop since you are already at the end of the file.

Comment: Hmm, you're right thanks... there must have had a slight difference somewhere between the example I posted and my actual code.

Comment: Ahh, I see now what is causing the issues.  If I take your example and try and change the file definitions to `filename template "sql_insert_template.sas";
filename dummy "sql_insert_template.sas";` then your code will only output the first observation (just like the original problem I was having).

Comment: Because the INFILE statement will not see any change in the physical filename so it does not close and reopen the file.

Comment: I still don't understand why that would make it read only 1 observation from sashelp.class though.

Comment: It reads the full input dataset for me. Put this line after the SET statement.   `putlog name= age=;`